# Double becomes 0 when multiplied with int

Tags: c, double, type-conversion

I am trying to store user input in seconds while the input is in minutes. If I input 0.1, this should be 6 seconds as 0.1 minute is 6 seconds.

However, my code results in zero for some reason.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if (argc != 6) {
                printf("Not enough arguments!\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        double sim_time, chance, time_served, sample_time;
        int num_tellers;


        sim_time = atoi(argv[1]) * 60; //These are in minute units
        chance = atoi(argv[2]);
        num_tellers = atoi(argv[3]);
        time_served = atoi(argv[4]) * 60;
        sample_time = atoi(argv[5]) * 60;
```

Here are the command line inputs: `./a.out 10 2 3 4 0.1`

Thus I expected `sample_time` to be 6, but it is 0. It may be something really dumb, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of [`atoi()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) is

```
 int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

It will return an `int` value, not a `float` or `double`. In your case, input `0.1` is returned as `0`.

If you want a `float` value, try [`atof()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof).

Note: as a suggestion, it's better to check for `NULL` before using the `argv[n]`s directly.

Comment: Oh I see. So is there something like atoi but returns a double or float?

Comment: @Renren29 Use `atof()`.

Comment: The code in the question already checked the `argv[n]` values by checking that `argc == 6`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `atof()` instead of `atoi()` when acting on floats/**doubles**.

`atoi()` returns integer

`atof()` returns **double**

About comment, for implementation purposes:

> double atof( const char *str );

If someone wouldn't know... difference between `double` and `float` is in precision.

Comment: Wrong. `atof()` returns `double`, not `float`.

Comment: Well... kind of true, but function name is from `float` - ato`f`(). Edited answer to be clear.

Comment: 'Kind of'...? To be even more precise: it returns a _floating-point type_ value, but there are three f-p types defined: `float`, `double` and `long double`, and the function actually returns `double`, not `float`.

Comment: Maybe not the best words... anyway as I said, edited answer, as it is important thing. Thank you.